# Search for a string in a specific branch across all my Organization repositories

Tags: github

My organization has my GitHub repositories. Every repository has mainly "main" branch and "dev" branch. I would like to search for a string in all the files only within "dev" branch across all the repositories.
Is there a way to achieve this via GitHub UI? I did not find any option to search, even "advanced search" doesn't seem to have filter by branch option.